# Disabling of JDBC masking in Application Insights Agent

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-application-insights

I'm attaching the latest Application Insight Java Agent (v3.4.16) programatically within my SpringBoot application (v3.1.3) as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-spring-boot#enabling-programmatically).

I do have `applicationinsights.json` with my configuration under `src/main/resources`. It looks like this (cf. [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-config#jdbc-query-masking)):

```json
{
  "selfDiagnostics": {
    "destination": "console",
    "level": "TRACE"
  },
  "instrumentation": {
    "jdbc": {
      "masking": {
        "enabled": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The logging level is recognize correctly, so the agent picks up the config file. I can even see stuff reported from my local instance to Azure after providing a valid connection string.

However I'm still not getting any SQL parameter resolution in the traces. The statements are still masked like this (from my local client logs):

```json
...
{"ver":2,"id":"3ce417f010b210df","name":"INSERT bubu.user_tbl",
"data":"insert into user_tbl (age,name,id) values (?,?,?)","type":"SQL",
"target":"localhost | bubu","duration":"00:00:00.005135","success":true}}}
...
```

[On Azure it looks exactly same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Taf3P.png). Any idea what I'm missing in order to get SQL parameters in the trace? Any help or advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried with the same configuration that which you tried in the above, and below is the result.

[image]

Here, my application is able to access the database so I would see dependency telemetry for those interactions but not the trace data.

[image]

Here, I made some changes in the **configuration file**.

```
{
  "selfDiagnostics": {
    "destination": "console",
    "level": "TRACE"
  },
  "instrumentation": {
    "jdbc": {
      "masking": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "trackPreparedStatement": {
        "enabled": true
      },
      "parameterCollectionEnabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

Then I am able get the Trace transaction with the dependency transaction with the SQL parameters.

**Result:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Cool, haven't seen this additional parameters ("parameterCollectionEnabled" and "trackPreparedStatement") ever before. Thanks a lot! Curious to know where you found them

Comment: I retrieved numerous websites, and I also personally made significant changes to the configuration.

Comment: @SureshChikkam tried provided config and both properties seem not existing for me:

`Unrecognized field "trackPreparedStatement" (class com.microsoft.applicationinsights.agent.internal.configuration.Configuration$DatabaseInstrumentationWithMasking), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "enabled", "masking"])`. Same is logged for "parameterCollectionEnabled", too. Any idea?